# Simple mathematical operation in the view is working in local but not in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to puts the result of this simple operation in my pack index view ( pack.quantity / pack.cigs.count).round(1)).
It works fine in local but does not work in heroku. In heroku I can see the result in some packs but not in all the packs.
I don't understand what is happening.
Thanks in advance.

```
    <% @packs.each do |pack| %>
      <li class="btn-green">
        <%= pack.start_date.strftime("%b %e") %>

        <% if pack.end_date %>
          <%= pack.end_date.strftime("%b %e") %>
          <%= "#{((pack.end_date - pack.start_date) / 60 / 60 / 24).round(1)} days" %>
        <% else %>
          <strong><%= 'not finished' %></strong>
          <%= "#{((Time.zone.now - pack.start_date) / 60 / 60 / 24).round(1)} days" %>
        <% end %>

        <% if pack.cigs.count > 0 %>
          <%= "#{pack.cigs.count} cigs" %>
          <%= pack.quantity %>
          <% if pack.quantity %>
            <%= "#{(pack.quantity / pack.cigs.count).round(1)} g/cigs" %>
          <% end %>

          <% if pack.price %>
            <%= "#{(pack.price / pack.cigs.count).round(1)} €/cigs" %>
          <% end %>

        <% end %>
```

Comment: I've tried to upload an image of my index view to stackoverflow but I can not link images until ten of reputation. In my local site I can see all the packs with their operation result correctly. But in heroku I can not see all the packs results. In some packs I can see the result but in others packs not.

Comment: What is the ouput that you are getting on Heroku?

Comment: @Among Hedge > In Heroku I can not see the result of this operation in all the packs lines. But in local I can.

Comment: @Among Hedge > I can not link an image of my view. It will better to explain with a little image. Sorry.

Comment: @sawa > My question is: Why, with the same code in local and Heroku, is not working fine in both sites.

Comment: I'm going to be boring, but, just a tip, you never should making operations in your views and keep the logic in your controllers

Comment: Thanks @escanxr I know it. But I'm very junior, so I prefer to write the logic, by first, in the view and later I refactor to the controller. It's no good but by the moment I'm doing it like that.

Comment: @escanxr Do you know how can I pass this formule <((pack.end_date - pack.start_date) / 60 / 60 / 24).round(1)> to the controller? I don't know how to do it because it is inside an each iterator. And the iterator must be in the pack-view to create the list. Thanks.

Comment: I know that is better to write the code in the controller instead of the view. But I think that the best is to write it in the model. Fat model, tinny controller. I don't know how to do this. I must to learn to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem.
The problem was the operation with two integer with not integer result.
    2 / 3 => 0
I've solved with to_f in the operation.
    2.t_f / 3 => 0.6666666666
That's all.
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the inconveniences. I'm very junior. I know this was the basics of Ruby but I have forget it. Thanks.